# problem in php code structure

Tags: php, mysql, loops, structure

i have a dynamically field that have a maximum of 4 inputs.

If i write 4 inputs that exists in the database i get

```
   input0 company // $num0
   "error" =  $num1
   input1 company // $num2
   "error" =  $num3
   input2 company // $num4
   "error" =  $num5
   input3 company // $num6
```

But if not exists in the database the order of first input is changed **because the while is not played:**

```
   "error" =  $num0
   input1 company // $num1
   and the order is changed....//problem
```

the main problem is that i need to know what is the input that exists in the database or not.

**script**

```
 function checkEmployeer($db, $form) {  
        $i=0;
        foreach ($form['job'] as $value) {

                $sql = $db -> prepare("SELECT `employer` FROM `employer` WHERE employer=?");

                $sql -> bind_param('s', $value);

                $sql -> execute();

                while ($sql -> fetch()) { //problem
                    ${'num'.$i++} = $value; //problem - $num0 = $value if exists in DB
                }   

                ${'num'.$i++} = "error"; //problem - $num0 or $num1 = depends of while result...    
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($form['job']); $i++) {

            if (${'num'.$i} != "error" && ${'num'.$i} == $form['job'][$i]) {
                echo ("already exists in the db".$i);
            }
            else {
                $sql = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO `database_charts`.`employer` (`employer`) VALUES (?)"); 

                $sql -> bind_param('s', $form['job'][$i]);

                $sql->execute();    
                echo ("insert");
            }
        }   
    }
```

how i can solve that? i don't have any idea...

Comment: Hi Fel, this question is a little bit unclear as is.

Comment: the problem is the order of $num. I need to identify what values exists in database. If exists ok, if not i need to insert in database this values.

Comment: question updated. I think that is more clear now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a key for employer and INSERT it without checking anything, affected_rows() will tell you if it has been inserted or not.
You will not get duplicates if `database_charts`.`employer` is defined as key.

Comment: your advice really simplify the problem. Thanks :)